# In oracle can we create table having column name from another table column value name?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there any way in oracle pl/sql to have a new table created which has column name coming from other table column data value.

For Example:

```
TableA

column1
-----------
A
B
C
D
```

out of this a new table comes out as

```
TABLE2

A B C D
- - - -
```

Where A,B,C,D act as column name for Table2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use PL/SQL to build a dynamic query and then use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA ( column1 ) AS
SELECT 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D' FROM DUAL;
```

**PL/SQL**:

```
DECLARE
  p_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT 'CREATE TABLE TableB ('
         || LISTAGG(
              column1 || ' NUMBER',
              ','
            ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM )
         || ')'
  INTO   p_sql
  FROM   TableA;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE p_sql;
END;
/
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM TableB;
```

```
 A |  B |  C |  D
-: | -: | -: | -:
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ff3ca89e40d90ff2e5be0e4da494b081)*

Comment: Hi, Thanks it produces the same result as expected. Really appreciate the quick reply.